# How to show a "Loading..." dialog in android?

Tags: android, android-dialog

How to create a dialog to show loading in android? I want to show a dialog with "Loading..."  while an aynctask i running. I tried with an activity with `Theme.Dialog`. Please help.

my code:

```java
private class getlisttask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        SourceURL srcGrabber = new SourceURL ();
        String result = "";

        try {               
              Url = Url + usr + "&qry=" + query;
              result = srcGrabber.grabSource(Url);               
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.tostring());
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        TextView txtView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView);
        txtView1.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: means are you want to show progress Dialog??

Comment: where is your asynctask code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ProgressDialog Class to show it.

```
/*****************************************
 * AsyncTask Class to Parse and Display
 ******************************************/
class AsyncTaskClassName extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, Void>{
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

    /* ***********************************
     * Pre-Execute Method 
     * ********************************** */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = util.getProgressDialog(ActivityClassName.this, "Please wait...", "Parsing List...    ");
           //ActivityClassName -> The Name of the Activity Class you want to show ProgressDialog
        // progressDialog.hide();
        progressDialog.show();

        /* Do your Pre-Execute Configuration */
    }

    /* ***********************************
     * Execute Method 
     * ********************************** */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        /* Do yourxec Task ( Load from URL) and return value */
        return null;
    }

    /* ***********************************
     * Post-Execute Method 
     * ********************************** */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

                    /* Do your Post -Execute Tasks */
    }
```

Comment: thanks. this is what i need. I searched about loader class, but this is exactly my requirement

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
      private ProgressDialog dialog1;
      dialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(LoginClass.this, "", "Loading...");
```